# select for multiple non-blocking connections

Tags: c, sockets

I have a single threaded program. It sends message to four destinations every five seconds. I don't want `connect()` to be blocked. So I am writing my program like this:

```
int              j, rc, non_blocking=1, sockets[4], max_fd=0;
struct sockaddr  server=get_server_addr();
fd_set           fdset;
const struct timeval  conn_timeout = { 2, 0 }; /* 2 seconds */

for (j=0; j<4; ++j)
{
    sockets[j]=socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    ioctl(sockets[j], FIONBIO, (char *)&non_blocking);
    connect(sockets[j], &server, sizeof (server));
}

/* prepare fd_set */
FD_ZERO ( &fdset );
for (j=0;j<4;++j)
{
    if (sockets[j] != -1 )
    {
        FD_SET ( sockets[j], &fdset );
        if ( sockets[j] > max_fd )
        {
             max_fd = sockets[j];
        }
    }
}

rc=select(max_fd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &conn_timeout );
if(rc > 0)
{
    for (j=0;j<4;++j)
    {
        if(sockets[j]!=-1 && FD_ISSET(sockets[j],&fdset))
        {
            /* send() */
        }
    }
}

/* close all valid sockets */
```

However, it seems `select()` returns immediately after ONE file descriptor is ready instead of blocking for `conn_timeout` (2 seconds). So in this case how can I achieve my targets?

1. The program continues if all sockets are ready.
2. The program can block there for 2 seconds if any one of sockets are not ready.

Comment: After your edit your targets are incomplete. What is the program supposed to do if only some of the sockets are ready?

Comment: Sorry, I did't make my point clear. If only some of the sockets are ready, the program is supposed to wait for 2 seconds and discard those sockets which are not ready.

Comment: Well that's exactly what happens, and select() is doing exactly what you need for that. So what's your question?

Comment: Like I said, the `select()` will return at once if any one of sockets are ready. What I am expecting is that it will block until all sockets are ready or timeout, either one is first.

Comment: Well it doesn't work like that, bad luck. You need to keep track of select entry and exit times yourself and maybe re-select for the remaining time in those sockets that weren't ready the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, `select` was designed on the assumption that you would want to service each socket as soon as it became ready.

If I understand what you're trying to do, then the simplest way to accomplish it will be to remove each socket from the fdset as it becomes ready.  If there are any sockets left in the set, use `gettimeofday` to adjust the timeout downward, and call `select` again.  When the set is empty, all four sockets are usable and you can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic approaches:

**If you want to stay strictly portable** you need to iterate:

- calculate end time from current time and timeout of your choice
- Cycle:
- --  Create fdset with those fds **not yet** ready
- --  calculate max time to wait
- --  `select()`
- --  remeber those fds that **are now** ready
- --  break if end time reached or all fds ready
- End cycle
- Now you have knowledge of the ready fds and the elapsed time

**If you want to stay portable, but can use threads**:

- start n threads
- select on one fd per thread
- join all threads

**If you do not need to be portable**: Most OSes have a facility for such a situation, e.g. Windows/.NET has WaitAll (together with async send and an event)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the connection between your stated targets and your stated problem. You are correct in saying that select() blocks until at least one socket is ready, but according to target #2 above that is exactly what you want. There's nothing in your stated targets about blocking until all four sockets are ready at the same time.

You should also note that sockets are almost always ready for writing, unless the send buffer is full, which means the receiver's receive buffer is full, which means the receiver is slower than the sender. So using select() alone as the underlying write timer isn't a good idea.